# Store/Read file in Postgres-DB

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to save a file in the database and I'm having trouble retrieving it.
The result is not a valid file.

Isolating part of the code, I think this should work:

```
$content = pg_escape_bytea (file_get_contents($tmp)); //image.jpg   
header('Content-type: ' . $mime); // image/jpg
echo pg_unescape_bytea($content); exit;
```

`$content` is stored, but I can't read it again!

What to do?

Comment: PHP version and PostgreSQL version? Any chance you're using an older PHP with a newer PostgreSQL that defaults to `bytea_output = hex`?

Comment: I don't see why you are using a postgresql escaping function on a binary file you load from the disk.

Comment: @greg file are from upload. I can insert and select $content again, but if this part don't work, nothing will work. Or do you mean that I do not need pg_escape_bytea before insert?

Comment: The question says: _I'm trying to save a file in the database and I'm having trouble retrieving it_, but the code shown doesn't do read nor write to the database. Show the code that does that.

Comment: @DanielVérité Really do not think it's necessary, but ... http://pastebin.com/KNWE4gg6

Comment: line 29 is just a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible explanation would be that you're in this configuration:

- the PHP side uses a `8.4` or older `libpq` library
- Server is `9.0` or newer
- the [bytea_output](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-BYTEA-OUTPU) config parameter is left to its default value (`hex`)

In this case, `pg_unescape_bytea` will not properly decode the bytea contents coming in text format from the database. As a workaround, you may add to the php code:

```
pg_query("SET bytea_output=escape");
```

before SELECTing the bytea contents and see if that makes a difference. If it does solve the problem you may make it a persistent setting for the database by issuing:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET bytea_output=escape;
```

until upgrading `libpq` to a newer version.